# Swift - Changing an array value of function call

Tags: function, swift, xcode6

I like to change an array value for my function call.

**Code for my ViewController2 that calls a function calculate**

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var springDisplacement : [Float] {return calculate(forceView2, stiffView2, springNumView2) }

}
```

**Code for function calculate**

```
public func calculateBoundary (f:[Float], s:[Float], n:NSInteger) -> (forceBound1:Float, forceBound2: Float, displacement:[Float]) {

    println("\nForces in the array are")
    for rows in 0...n{
        if(rows==0||rows==n)
        { f[rows] = 0.0 }                
            println(f[rows])          
        }
}
```

I have an error: '@lValue $T5' is not identical to 'Float', when i want to change my f[rows] = 0.0

Any advices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `f` parameter is an `immutable array`. You can change this to a `mutable array` parameter by using the function signature as follows

```
func calculateBoundary (var f:[Float], var s:[Float], n:NSInteger)  -> (forceBound1:Float, forceBound2: Float, displacement:[Float]) { // }
```

If you want to also modify the original arrays passed to the function, you need to use `inout` parameters.

```
func calculateBoundary (inout f:[Float],inout s:[Float], n:NSInteger) -> (forceBound1:Float, forceBound2: Float, displacement:[Float]) { // }
```

You can call it like this

```
var f : [Float] = [1.0,2.0]
var g : [Float] = [1.0,2.0]

let result = calculateBoundary(&f, &g, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

`f array` is not mutable. You need to pass the `f` array [as `inout` parameter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html):

```
 func calculateBoundary (inout f:[Float], s:[Float], n:NSInteger) -> (forceBound1:Float, forceBound2: Float, displacement:[Float]) {...}
```

Then you can call `calculateBoundary` like this:

```
var springDisplacement : [Float] {return calculate(&forceView2, stiffView2, springNumView2) }
```

Comment: `var springDisplacement : [Float] {return calculate(&forceView2, stiffView2, springNumView2) }` gives me an error: 'inout [(Float)]' is not convertible to '[Float]'. I have declared my f and forceView2 to be array of type float.